# Pentaho Report Designer crosstab is not grouping columns properly

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer, pentaho-design-studio

I was creating a crosstab in Pentaho Report Designer 7.0 and expeting output like this,
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C440B.png)

Unfortunately, I am getting output as below,
[Output getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdCcq.png)

**It is simply not grouping the nested column component properly.**

Answer (score 0):

Did you put in the correct way when create crosstab?

```
Row Axis - Row_title_2, Row_title_2
Column Axis - Group_x
Data Cells - column_title_1, column_title_2, column_title_3
```